# Magnific popup displays only the first id

Tags: php, html, popup, magnific-popup

```
<!-- Start of Quick View -->
                                    <div class="product product-single product-popup" id="popup_detail<?php echo $row[0]; ?>" >
                                        <div class="row gutter-lg">
                                            <div class="col-md-6 mb-4 mb-md-0">
                                                <div class="product-gallery product-gallery-sticky">
                                                    <div class="swiper-container product-single-swiper swiper-theme nav-inner">
                                                        <div class="swiper-wrapper row cols-1 gutter-no">
                                                            <?php
                                                                for ($i = 0; $i < count($images)-1; $i++)
                                                                {
                                                                    ?>
                                                                        <div class="swiper-slide">
                                                                            <figure class="product-image">
                                                                                <img src="images/images/gallery/preview/<?php echo trim($images[$i]); ?>"
                                                                                    data-zoom-image="images/images/gallery/original/<?php echo trim($images[$i]); ?>"
                                                                                    alt="Water Boil Black Utensil" width="800" height="900">
                                                                            </figure>
                                                                        </div>
                                                                    <?php
                                                                }
                                                            ?>
                                                            
                                                        </div>
                                                        <button class="swiper-button-next"></button>
                                                        <button class="swiper-button-prev"></button>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="product-thumbs-wrap swiper-container" data-swiper-options="{
                                                        'navigation': {
                                                            'nextEl': '.swiper-button-next',
                                                            'prevEl': '.swiper-button-prev'
                                                        }
                                                    }">
                                                        <div class="product-thumbs swiper-wrapper row cols-4 gutter-sm">
                                                            <?php
                                                                for ($i = 0; $i < count($images)-1; $i++)
                                                                {
                                                                    ?>
                                                                        
                                                                        <div class="product-thumb swiper-slide">
                                                                            <img src="images/images/gallery/preview/<?php echo trim($images[$i]); ?>" alt="Product Thumb" width="103"
                                                                                height="116">
                                                                        </div>
                                                                        
                                                                    <?php
                                                                }
                                                            ?>
                                                        </div>  
                                                        <button class="swiper-button-next"></button>
                                                        <button class="swiper-button-prev"></button>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-md-6 overflow-hidden p-relative">
                                                <div class="product-details scrollable pl-0">
                                                    <h2 class="product-title">A</h2>
                                                    <div class="product-bm-wrapper">
                                                        <figure class="brand">
                                                            <img src="assets/assets/images/products/brand/brand-11.jpg" alt="Brand" width="102" height="48" />
                                                        </figure>
                                                        <div class="product-meta">
                                                            <div class="product-categories">
                                                                Kategoria:
                                                                <span class="product-category"><a href="#">Elektronikë</a></span>
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="product-sku">
                                                                ID: <span><?php echo $row[0]; ?></span>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>

                                                    <hr class="product-divider">

                                                    <div class="product-price"><?php echo $row["product_price"]; ?> €</div>

                                                    <div class="ratings-container">
                                                        <div class="ratings-full">
                                                            <span class="ratings" style="width: 80%;"></span>
                                                            <span class="tooltiptext tooltip-top"></span>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <a href="#" class="rating-reviews">(3 Blerje)</a>
                                                    </div>

                                                    <div class="product-short-desc">
                                                        <ul class="list-type-check list-style-none">
                                                            <li>Mikro-Çip Eksternal 1GB+</li>
                                                            <li>Ekrani Touch Screen TFT LCD me kamerë front face</li>
                                                            <li>Përgjigje apo thirrje direkte nga ora</li>
                                                        </ul>
                                                    </div>

                                                    <hr class="product-divider">

                                                    <div class="product-form product-variation-form product-color-swatch">
                                                        <label>Ngjyra:</label>
                                                        <div class="d-flex align-items-center product-variations">
                                                            <a href="#" class="color" style="background-color: #ffcc01"></a>
                                                            <a href="#" class="color" style="background-color: #ca6d00;"></a>
                                                            <a href="#" class="color" style="background-color: #1c93cb;"></a>
                                                            <a href="#" class="color" style="background-color: #ccc;"></a>
                                                            <a href="#" class="color" style="background-color: #333;"></a>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="product-form product-variation-form product-size-swatch">
                                                        <label class="mb-1">Madhësia:</label>
                                                        <div class="flex-wrap d-flex align-items-center product-variations">
                                                            <a href="#" class="size">S</a>
                                                            <a href="#" class="size">L</a>
                                                            <a href="#" class="size">XL</a>
                                                            <a href="#" class="size">XXL</a>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <a href="#" class="product-variation-clean">Hjek filtrin</a>
                                                    </div>

                                                    <div class="product-variation-price">
                                                        <span></span>
                                                    </div>

                                                    <div class="product-form">
                                                        <div class="product-qty-form">
                                                            <div class="input-group">
                                                                <input class="quantity form-control" type="number" min="1" max="10000000">
                                                                <button class="quantity-plus w-icon-plus"></button>
                                                                <button class="quantity-minus w-icon-minus"></button>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-cart">
                                                            <i class="w-icon-cart"></i>
                                                            <span>Shto në shportë</span>
                                                        </button>
                                                    </div>

                                                    <div class="social-links-wrapper">
                                                        <div class="social-links">
                                                            <div class="social-icons social-no-color border-thin">
                                                                <a href="#" class="social-icon social-facebook w-icon-facebook"></a>
                                                                <a href="#" class="social-icon social-twitter w-icon-twitter"></a>
                                                                <a href="#" class="social-icon social-pinterest fab fa-pinterest-p"></a>
                                                                <a href="#" class="social-icon social-whatsapp fab fa-whatsapp"></a>
                                                                <a href="#" class="social-icon social-youtube fab fa-linkedin-in"></a>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <span class="divider d-xs-show"></span>
                                                        <div class="product-link-wrapper d-flex">
                                                            <a href="#" class="btn-product-icon btn-wishlist w-icon-heart"><span></span></a>
                                                            <a href="#"
                                                                class="btn-product-icon btn-compare btn-icon-left w-icon-compare"><span></span></a>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- End of Quick view -->
```

When user clicks, show popup dialog

```
<div class="product-action"><a href="#popup_detail<?php echo $row[0]; ?>" name="item_detail" id="B" class="popup-with-zoom-anim btn-quickview"><i class="fa fa-eye fa-2x" aria-hidden="true" style="color:#696b6a; margin-top: -5px;"></i>Show Detail</a>
```

The result is the same for all items, that means when click 'Show Detail' link, it displays only the first item in the fetched list query. However, if we inspect the page for a moment we can see that all the element items in the loop have been loaded properly with images and other corresponding data.
As you can see from the code, the popup dialog id is unique `id="popup_detail<?php echo $row["item_id"]; ?>"` with the 'Show Detail' link `a href="#popup_detail<?php echo $row["item_id"]; ?>"`

I have tried to put the entire Quick View section outside the `while` loop, but then it shows the last item id from the query fetched! In fact, it doesn't show the data (id, item_name) but the item images only! I'm stuck trying to solve this for days and still not able to make it working.

Thank you.

Comment: _"As you can see from the code, the popup dialog id is unique `id="popup_detail<?php echo $row["item_id"]; ?>"`"_ - only it is `<?php echo $row[0]; ?>` in the actual code you have shown us ...?

Comment: I have tried unique id="popup_detail<?php echo $row["item_id"]; ?>" and unique ahref="popup_detail<?php echo $row["item_id"]; ?>" but the same problem again

Comment: So what do you see in the generated HTML code then, do the elements all have their own, unique ID value?

Comment: Yes, they generate unique id like this id="popup_detail446" , id="popup_detail447" , id="popup_detail448" and so on... but still same problem